# How to stop OS X compiling/converting .plist files

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I'm currently setting up a few OS X clients and servers and frequently need to open/edit .plist files.  Annoyingly OS X compiles these plist files into a binary format, presumably to speed up reading them for performance reasons, which is great except I need to convert them back to xml every time I need to open them which is more important to me than a insignificant performance boost.

So I have to either:

1. Use Plist editor - I don't like it and it requires Xcode to be installed - not always feasible on a client machine.
2. Convert them using plutil: `plutil -convert xml1 file.plist` - which is a PITA.

Is there a way of stopping OS X from converting the nice XML plists to the Devils' binary format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the format of a property list file is completely determined by the program that creates/updates the file. The [Cocoa property list serialization methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-SW6) and [those of Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001210-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_4) all take a format option that lets the program specify either “XML” or “binary”; there is no value like “use some externally specified default”. Programs could conceivably do their own defaulting based on some centralized setting, but I am not aware of any such setting (of course it could just be undocumented; the point is that it would still be limited to only the applications that adopted such a “manual defaulting” convention).

---

[*PlistBuddy*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) is a flexible and mostly scriptable property list editor (e.g. [*defaults*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) will only access/modify values at the “top level” of the property list, but *PlistBuddy* can access/modify values at any arbitrary depth). It is available at `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` on 10.5 and later. It was not bundled with the system on 10.4, but you can usually find it as one of `/Library/Receipts/*/Contents/Resources/PlistBuddy` (e.g. `/Library/Receipts/iTunesX.pkg/Contents/Resources/PlistBuddy`).

E.g.

- inspect a property list file

  ```
  PlistBuddy -c print /path/to/some/plist/file
  ```
- clear out (or create) a plist file and set `CFBundleIdentifier` to `com.apple.plistbuddy`

  ```
  PlistBuddy -c 'clear dict' \
             -c 'add :CFBundleIdentifier string' \
             -c 'set :CFBundleIdentifier com.apple.plistbuddy' \
      /path/to/some/plist/file
  ```

You could also use [*osascript*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) to run commands from *System Events*’ “Property List Suite”. It is certainly not as convenient to run from a shell command line, but would be fine for more automated inspections and modifications (i.e. done by a script). The commands from this suite offer write access on 10.5 and later (10.4 was read-only).